# Override BackButton while menu is Open

Tags: java, android, back-button

What I am trying to achieve is when the user clicks the back button while the `MENU` is visible, the `menuActual` and `MENU`'s state changes from visible to invisible. If the `MENU` is not open and the user clicks back, then a `Toast` is displayed saying `"Press again to Exit"`, and if you click back within 2 seconds the application will close.

Code that I have:

```
@Override
    public void finish() {

    if (MENU.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        MENU.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        menuActual.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }else {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            moveTaskToBack(true);

            return;
        }else {

            this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Tap again to Exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    }
}`
```

I have declared `boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;`

The application goes as far as displaying the `Toast` saying `"Press again to Exit"`, but if back is clicked again the application says `"AppName isn't responding"`

Struggling to figure out why this is, been a long day.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in `onBackPressed` like this :

```
private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (MENU.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        MENU.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        menuActual.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return;
    }

    if (!doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Tap again to Exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(runnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
            }
        }, 2000);
        return;
    }

    // Removes the callBack
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);

    // Replace this next line with finishAffinity() if you want to close the app.
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```